# Is this likely to be a Wi-Fi deauthentication attack?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration, attack-vector

Lately our Wi-Fi connection on a certain band has been terrible. No matter what settings I choose and also after a reset and with all kinds of old and new Wi-Fi router firmware we keep getting very, very slow connection.

Tried WireShark too, getting lots of TCP Retransmission and TCP Spurious Retransmission packets.

But when I use a MAC-filter and whitelist our own devices then the connection is much, much better. Though we are still receiving "deauth" log messages.

Here below is a snippet from the System Log from our RT-AX92U router now running most recent firmware again. Or actually there are two of them running in AiMesh mode.

It is the 5GHz-2 (the 'backhaul' for communication between the two routers) that has that problem.

Also tried Repeater-mode but same thing on second 5 GHz band. Also tried to disable lots of things and re-enabling them. Roaming Assistant is currently still disabled.

Could there be other causes for the "Deauth_ind" and such in the below snippet?

```
Jan 17 07:55:47 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth6: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A0, status: 0, reason: Disassociated due to inactivity (4)
Jan 17 07:57:01 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(432): eth5: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A4, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 07:57:01 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(460): eth5: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A4, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 07:58:54 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(432): eth6: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:DE, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 07:58:54 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(460): eth6: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:DE, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 08:54:48 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(432): eth6: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A0, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 08:54:48 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(460): eth6: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A0, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 08:56:44 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Deauthenticated because sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3)
Jan 17 08:56:44 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Class 3 frame received from nonassociated station (7)
Jan 17 08:56:44 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Class 3 frame received from nonassociated station (7)
Jan 17 08:56:44 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Class 3 frame received from nonassociated station (7)
Jan 17 08:56:44 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Class 3 frame received from nonassociated station (7)
Jan 17 08:56:45 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(432): eth7: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 08:56:45 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(442): eth7: ReAssoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 08:59:08 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth7: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Unspecified reason (1)
Jan 17 09:13:06 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth6: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A0, status: 0, reason: Disassociated due to inactivity (4)
Jan 17 09:13:19 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(432): eth6: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A0, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 09:13:19 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(442): eth6: ReAssoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A0, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 09:23:23 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth6: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A0, status: 0, reason: Station requesting (re)association is not authenticated with responding station (9)
Jan 17 09:23:29 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(432): eth7: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 09:23:29 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(460): eth7: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 09:24:04 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(432): eth5: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 09:24:04 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(460): eth5: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 09:24:04 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(414): eth7: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8)
Jan 17 09:24:04 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(414): eth7: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8)
Jan 17 09:24:06 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(397): eth5: Deauth_ind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Unspecified reason (1)
Jan 17 09:24:06 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(414): eth5: Disassoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: Disassociated because sending station is leaving (or has left) BSS (8)
Jan 17 09:24:07 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(432): eth7: Auth XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
Jan 17 09:24:07 wlceventd: CAP,F4:90: wlceventd_proc_event(460): eth7: Assoc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:30, status: 0, reason: d11 RC reserved (0)
```

Comment: Hey there, do you have DFS (Dynamic Frequency Selection) channels enabled in your router settings?

Comment: Also see https://www.snbforums.com/threads/asus-rt-ac88u-firmware-version-3-0-0-4-384-81116.59170/#post-541794

Comment: Looks like a deauth attack - I would recommend buying a newer wireless router and switching WPS off, along with a WPA2 password of over 24 characters.

Comment: I already have a very long WPA2 password. Don't need a newer router. Also have WPS disabled last time I checked. And filtering seems to help so best not to disable it?

Comment: DFS? Enabled and disabled it but it had no positive effects so it seems.

Comment: It seems my connection issues do seem to be related to MAC filtering. But I don't know what's causing the issue exactly. I've got the MAC filtering enabled, instead of disabled. First whitelisted a bunch of addresses but it's much easier just to put it in Reject mode and have an empty list... Seems to work fine when enabled (and not so much when disabled).

Comment: @Wieger I have a similar issue but it happens only every hour... a macOS client getting "Deauth_ind" reason code=3 (sending station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS (3)). I don't have MAC filtering. Are you saying you no longer see this problem after you enable MAC filtering?

Comment: I have the same router you do, and I see events like this in the log for one particular client (not the mesh node).  I think it may have to do with the "handoff" when moving between nodes, the `Deauth_ind` line being the "losing" station trying to nudge the client to the "gaining" station.  Could it be that the signal is too weak for your backhaul?  Does this happen if you leave the node closer to the main router?

Comment: Sorry but I got so tired and it was real scary so I sent this mesh set off to a (rather big) church. Better to be safe than sorry I guess. Thought they'll know what to do with it!

Comment: I hope your church figures it out.  I'm pretty sure this is a bug in the stock firmware -- simply rebooting the whole setup caused the problem client to start working again, but I assume it'll start acting up if I wait long enough.